# Attempting to use Lotus Notes IDXLExporter in .net results in System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: .net, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I'm attempting to utilize the IDXLExporter interface in .net to open a IBM Notes Documents with attachments. Most of the documents get pulled in fine but we've stumbled upon some documents that are particularly large. These are resulting in System.OutOfMemoryException Errors.

```
   Dim DxlE As IDXLExporter = nSession.CreateDXLExporter()
            DxlE.ConvertNotesbitmapsToGIF = True
            DxlE.ExitOnFirstFatalError = True

            Dim szDocxml As String

            'todo this is where we error out
            szDocxml = DxlE.Export(ND)
```

Any Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you running in a 64-bit .NET environment?

Comment: No the Domino dll is 32 bit only. Thanks Richard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is this. We were getting large stacks of data coming back from Domino in single documents and blowing up our string buffer. The work around was not to do this but to try to break your documents up into their constituent pieces and process them that way rather than trying to work our way through an entire document at a time via the xml response from domino. Also paying very close attention to GC is crucial. Disposing the notes session and restarting it periodically helped reduce/eliminate crashing.